# Every time I use the button with the macro, it generates a “VBA Query ERROR 2”

Tags: vba

Every time I use the button with the macro, it generates an error that the query already exists, how do I generate a new query automatically?

Here's the code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="ATDFIM", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Fonte = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""\\192.168.79.202\jotanunes\DIRETORIA_ADM\COMERCIAL\CORPORACAO\FECHAMENTO MENSAL\RELATORIO FECHAMENTO 2022\DOC\ATDFIM.csv""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=30, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Cabeçalhos Promovidos"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Fonte, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Tipo Alterado"" = Table.Tr" & _
        "ansformColumnTypes(#""Cabeçalhos Promovidos"",{{""Protocolo"", type number}, {""Cliente"", type text}, {""Data de cadastro"", type date}, {""Data da situação"", type date}, {""Situação"", type text}, {""Assunto"", type text}, {""Subassunto"", type text}, {""Empreendimento"", type text}, {""Sigla"", type text}, {""Etapa"", type text}, {""Bloco"", type text}, {""Unida" & _
        "de(s)"", type text}, {""Região do Empreendimento"", type text}, {""Origem"", type text}, {""Corretor"", type text}, {""Imobiliária"", type text}, {""Prioridade"", type text}, {""Classificação"", type text}, {""Tipo"", type text}, {""Título do atendimento"", type text}, {""Descrição"", type text}, {""Canal"", type text}, {""Humor do Cliente"", type text}, {""Encerrad" & _
        "o no primeiro contato"", type text}, {""Qtd. mensagens"", Int64.Type}, {""Qtd. interações"", Int64.Type}, {""Time"", type text}, {""Regiões do Time"", type text}, {""Tempo até finalizar o atendimento"", type text}, {""Sinalizador jurídico"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Tipo Alterado"""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Query ERROR](https://superuser.com/questions/1739822/vba-query-error)

Comment: Do not post the same question multiple times.